# adding multiple wcf service references in the same name space

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have 8 wcf services, would like to have them in the same namespace when I add in the visual studio. I tried Service references -> Add Service Reference but every one creating their names space. Please let me know if you need more information !

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the namespace from visual studio. However you can use wsdl.exe to generate the proxy/service reference by hand:

[wsdl.exe msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx)

Use the /namespace parameter to generate in a specific namespace:

> /n[amespace]:namespace   Specifies the namespace for the generated
>   proxy or template. The default namespace is the global namespace. When
>   using the /parameters option, this value is the  element
>   and contains a string. This element must be in the parameters file.